# How do I reference a subclass's parent view controller?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates

Here you can see that I've set the delegate of my subclassed textView to itself:

```
import Foundation
class ImageCaptionTextView: UITextView, UITextViewDelegate {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        delegate = self
    }
```

Now in my controller my delegate methods do not work. I'm using all the ImageCaptionTextView delegate methods in the ImageCaptionTextView subclass instead of where they previously were which was the controllers class.

Now there is some code I needed to add to the controller related textViewDidEndEditing delegate method for the ImageCaptionTextView but because the delegate method for the ImageCaptionTextView is set inside the ImageCaptionTextView subclass this new code added in controller won't work.

I'm starting to wonder whether I've just complicated things and should just move as much code as I can back into the controller. I just thought it made things a little cleaner for me.

**So my question is:**

How can I reference the ImageCaptionTextView's parent controller so instead of setting ImageCaptionTextView's delegate to itself i can set it to the controller?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the delegate methods and then send the same message to the controller, but honestly that's naughty.

Consider doing everything you can in a controller using delegate methods before subclassing.  If you hit something that the delegate methods won't handle, subclass, but change as little as possible with the view class implementation.

Comment: This was the way in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you..

First you need to define a delegate variable in your UITextView. This is a possible way to set it up:

```
class ImageCaptionTextView: UITextView, UITextViewDelegate {

    var delegate: UITextViewDelegate!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // delegate = self
    }
}
```

The exclamation mark means that the variable isn't yet initialised at declaration time but that it will latter in the code. It is thus not an optional and MUST be initialised somewhere.

Then in your UIViewController, you initialise that variable with a reference to your UITextView. An outlet in the storyboard should do the trick. If you have set the UIView programatically, it's even easier.

IBOutlet way:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageCaptionTextView: UITextView!

// later in the code

imageCaptionTextView.delegate = self
```

Programatically:

```
let imageCaptionTextView = ImageCaptionTextView()
imageCaptionTextView.delegate = self
```

You should be good then ;)

Comment: Marked up because this worked but I went with another answer and kept everything in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used swift before, but if it works like Objective-C, then the way to do this is to set your UITextView subclass's delegate property to it's parent view controller at the moment that it's created. i.e.

In parent VC (forgive me if it's in obj-c):

```
ImageCaptionTextView *myTextView = [ImageCaptionTextView new];
myTextView.delegate = self;
```

If this doesn't make any sense in swift then I'll just delete this answer. But I hope it helps!

Comment: I was just thinking about this. Somehow have the delegate set to the controller when the textView is initialised.
I tried making a connection in interface builder from the textView to the controller. Tested and it didn't work.

Comment: Mmh. Not sure I can help you there, as I'm not that experienced with IB either. Just programmatic, all the way (should really branch out sometime...). Anyway, if I were you I'd put that edit in your question (including a screen shot of your IB connection), it'll get it back on top of the queue and maybe somebody with IB/swift experience will be able to help).